# Batch insertion in RxJava-JDBC

Tags: rx-java, batch-insert

I have a list of data to be inserted into database. My current solution with RxJava-JDBC looks like the following code snippet:

```
String sql_batch_insert = "insert into ... values(?, ?);
Observable<List<..>> data = ...;
data.flatMap(list ->
    Observable.from(list)
        .flatMap(pair ->
            database.update(sql_batch_insert)
                .parameters(table_name, pair.getKey(), pair.getValue())
                .count()
        )
)
```

How can I do batch insertion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from Github project: I can call batchSize(int) on Builder object returned from insert(...) method